# Points to focus on while making a video of an online teaching demonstration for a university teaching position application

Tags: mathematics, teaching, job-search, online-learning, lecture-teaching-method

I've applied for a mathematics teaching position at a university, and as part of the application process, I'm supposed to submit a video of my teaching. The exact guideline says:

"*Select a small piece of content and produce a short video (not more than 5 minutes) of the sort that you would upload to Moodle if you were teaching this module remotely this term. This video does not have to be completely self-contained but can be a snapshot of what you would do for 5 minutes of a long lecture.*"

I'm supposed to share a link to this video with the recruitment team.

This question is about how to make this video optimal without spending any money on video editing. **In my case, I'll state a theorem**. Here are some tricks I think that may work in making a better video, assuming that the students are watching me in real time:

1. Instead of writing a whole theorem by hand, take a screenshot of the theorem from a book, and then paste it onto the virtual board, and then explain the theorem. This'll save time.
2. Since the video would only last 5 minutes, I think it's best to go over examples and counter examples and geometric demonstration (wherever applicable) instead of a proof, since proofs often take long. This'll make the students get a "feel" for the theorem.
3. Perhaps an auto generated subtitle (although not sure how to add it to my video, suggestions appreciated).
4. Remembering the introduction part very well and and pretty much saying it in the beginning, instead of thinking on the spot, which is fine in a classroom setting, but may not be good in a video, just in case the applicant murmurs or pauses to think etc.
5. It goes without saying, but **not** rushing.

**Any other pointers? Or please do feel free to correct the above points.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe post on math educators for a more targeted audience response?

Comment: You need to script it and do it multiple times, you definitely should not be thinking on the spot for this.   Math is a very specific discipline with different approaches.  You might want to see if the department has said anything about active learning or its focus.  Also make sure you understand the student audience ... but the problem with teaching demos is that the real audience is the faculty.  I'd write a short intro and follow up that frame the video in a larger lesson.